# How do I remove the square brackets from my array/list

Tags: python, arrays, excel, list

I have the following code. This is pulling the value 0.025 from an excel file.

```
import random,xlrd
fileWorkspace = "/Users/Bob/Desktop/"

wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(fileWorkspace + "Excel.xlsx")
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)

dist,numbers = [],[]
for a in range(0,sh1.nrows):
    dist.append(str(sh1.cell(a,0).value))
    numbers.append(str(sh1.cell(a,1).value))
print(dist)
print(numbers)

if "expovariate" in dist:
    values = next((item.split(',') for item in numbers if item), None)
    ev_1 = [float(x) for x in values]
    ev = random.expovariate(ev_1)
    print(ev)
```

I don't know what is happening?

[image: Excel File Image]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.expovariate *lambd is 1.0 divided by the desired mean. It should be nonzero.*

Comment: I can't do array[0]. In excel, that value may be in any row of that particular column

Comment: @BobH., add that to your question and expand with more examples as it is unclear how it would not work, are you sure the other error is not `for /: 'float' and 'str'`?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham I updated the original code. Please look.

Comment: Remember I have the if statement because I am doing the same thing for other distributions such as normalvariate, uniform, etc. They all work fine because they have two parameters that they take in, but expovariate only takes one, so that's where the problem comes in. So, keep all those lines in there or try to atleast.

Comment: @BobH. so you want to call `expovariate` for each x in `values`?

Comment: If the column has the word "expovariate" in it, then look the column next to it, and use that value to calculate the exporvariate value with that random.expovariate function

Comment: I recommend you make an excel file because it is hard to explain. In the first column put expovariate for any row, and then right beside it in the next column put 0.025. It doesn't work because expovariate only takes one parameter. Similarly, instead of expovariate, try gammavariate, and put 1,2 instead 0.025. That will work. I don't care how you get it to calculate as long as you can do it.

Comment: @ozgur Are you still trying?

Comment: @BobH, what is in `[float(x) for x in values]`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That is what is pulling/using 0.025 from excel

Comment: @BobH.,  split returns a list so you are iterating over a list of values in  `[float(x) for x in values]`, what do you want to do with those values?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't know. You can remove that. As I said I am using the code for multiple distributions. Do it however you want to. I just want it to work.

Comment: @BobH., my point is without knowing what is in values it is impossible to suggest something, if you added a sample of data it would be a lot easier

Comment: Ok hold on let me post an image of the excel file i am using.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I just added the image.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Are you still trying it >

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `array[0]` for this to work. You're passing in a list instead of the floating point number, so you need to index the list to grab this value.

Since you said this is from an excel file. You can use something like the `csv` module to read the excel file iterate over the rows or row if you have a singular row and look for that value since you don't know where the value is at in the row/column.

Comment: I can't do array[0]. In excel, that value may be in any row of that particular column

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = random.expovariate(array[0])
```

Comment: I can't do array[0]. In excel, that value may be in any row of that particular column.

Comment: So why don't you elaborate your question with an example so we can have a better understanding on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Okay I will need create it for that. I will need some time. Can you wait for about 15 mins?

Comment: Done. Look at the edit.